# What is the difference between startFlow and startTrackedFlow in Corda?

Tags: blockchain, corda

So what is the advantage of using startTrackedFlow over startFlow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is defined in [the official documentation](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.5/flow-state-machines.html#starting-your-flow):

> The process of starting a flow returns a FlowHandle that you can use to observe the result, and which also contains a permanent identifier for the invoked flow in the form of the StateMachineRunId. Should you also wish to track the progress of your flow (see Progress tracking) then you can invoke your flow instead using CordaRPCOps.startTrackedFlowDynamic or any of its corresponding CordaRPCOps.startTrackedFlow extension functions. These will return a FlowProgressHandle, which is just like a FlowHandle except that it also contains an observable progress field.